# MongoDB query to return docs based on an array size after filtering array of JSON objects?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I have MongoDB documents structured in this way:

```
[
  {
    "id":  "car_1",
    "arrayProperty": [
      {
        "model": "sedan",
        "turbo": "nil"
      },
      {
        "model": "sedan",
        "turbo": "60cc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":  "car_2",
    "arrayProperty": [
      {
        "model": "coupe",
        "turbo": "50cc"
      },
      {
        "model": "coupe",
        "turbo": "60cc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to make a find query that translates into basic English as "Ignoring all models that have 'nil' value for 'turbo', return all documents with arrayProperty of length X."  **That is to say, the "arrayProperty" of car 1 would be interpreted as having a size of 1, while the array of car 2 would have a size of 2.  The goal is to be able to make a query for all cars with arrayProperty size of 2 and only see car 2 returned in the results.**

Without ignoring the nil values, the query is very simple as:

```
{ arrayProperty: { $size: 2} }
```

And this would return both cars 1 and 2. Moreover, if our array was just a simple array such as:

```
[1,2,3,'nil]
```

Then our query is simply:

```
{
  arrayProperty: {
    $size: X,
    $ne: "nil"
  }
}
```

However, when we introduce an array of JSON objects, things get tricky.  I have tried numerous things to no avail including:

```
  "arrayProperty": {
    $size: 2,
    $ne: {"turbo": "nil"}
  }

  "arrayProperty": {
    $size: 2,
    $ne: ["arrayProperty.turbo": "nil"]
  }
```

Even without the `$size` operator in there, I can't seem to filter by the nil value.  Does anyone know how I would properly do this in those last two queries?

Answer (score 0):

use `$and` in `$match`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "$and": [
        {
          arrayProperty: {
            $size: 2
          }
        },
        {
          "arrayProperty.turbo": {
            $ne: "nil"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eve44cdIpoW)

---

use `$set` first

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "arrayProperty": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$arrayProperty",
          "as": "a",
          "cond": {
            $ne: [
              "$$a.turbo",
              "nil"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      arrayProperty: {
        $size: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BSTeNeNl1wR)

---

set a new field of size

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "size": {
        $size: {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$arrayProperty",
            "as": "a",
            "cond": {
              $ne: [
                "$$a.turbo",
                "nil"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      size: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FXMHPhN95JC)

Comment: While this does return the correct car for this specific query, I am looking for a query that would also return car 1 if we specified the size as 1.  The idea here would be that if "turbo" is "nil" then we will simply not count that in the size.  Is this possible?

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Cool, I think I can use $expr to use this in the find {} queries too, as this is aggregation logic.  May I ask if you can see a way where the "nil" value would still be included when we query for a size of 1?  I see it is literally removed.  Maybe not possible, just checking.

Comment: I update my answer